# How to automatically map view-columns to their original columns for inserting into source-tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I'm currently looking for a ***general*** way for handling insert-statements on (fairly simple) PostgreSQL views which will not be fragile to column-name changes or the addition of new columns. The goal would be to build `INSTEAD`-triggers which will not require maintenance and can be easily applied to new views which share a similar form.

In other words, this would be a formula for providing table-like access to certain views which would allow them to be accessed in a table-like fashion. Of course, this would not be done with the goal of fooling anyone into thinking something's a table, but rather to simplify things for myself and the others who will be adding records to the database, many of whom are going to come running to me if any trigger-code breaks on them.

The reason for wanting something like that would be to deal with situations wherein creating a record requires pre-existing records to already exist:

```
CREATE TABLE bar (
        bar_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        bar_a CHAR
);

CREATE TABLE foo (
        foo_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        foo_a BIGINT,
        bar_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES bar(bar_id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS
        SELECT 
                foo_id, 
                bar_id, 
                foo_a AS num, 
                bar_a AS let 
        FROM (foo RIGHT JOIN bar ON foo.bar_id = bar.bar_id);
```

Being able to insert straight into a view like this would be a nice way of holding all of the limes without dropping them; database constraints are great to keep your system in order, but they can get in the way when you're running a session and just trying to get some records in without it taking all day. Having a trigger handle that in the case of dependencies allows the best of both worlds.

Concretely, this would mean something that can be used to run code like

```
INSERT INTO bar (let) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO foo (num,foo_fk) VALUES (1,currval(bar_bar_id_seq)); 
-- currval only pays attention to the last insert which happens on your OWN connection, 
-- meaning it is safe to use it here
```

on `INSERT` to the view. The hope would be that the trigger would not be sensitive to column-names being altered and the view being modified, such that throwing a well-formed `INSERT` at the view will result in success without the trigger-function needing frequent tweaks for small changes.

### Mapping view-columns to table-columns (the main challenge)

Clearly the information for this *must* be stored hidden in some form or other, but the hardest part of this (given my understanding) is determining the mapping between view-columns and source-table columns without human intervention. For the `INSERT`-trigger function to be robust, this information has to be dug up from somewhere.

Ideally, [view_column_usage](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/infoschema-view-column-usage.html) would have a structure like this:

```
view_catalog|view_schema|view_name|table_catalog|table_schema|table_name|source_col|view_col|
------------+-----------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+--------+
 db1        | public    | view1   | db1         | public     | bar      | bar_a    | let    |
 db1        | public    | view1   | db1         | public     | bar      | bar_id   | ----   |
 db1        | public    | view1   | db1         | public     | foo      | foo_a    | num    |
 db1        | public    | view1   | db1         | public     | foo      | foo_fk   | bar_id |
 db1        | public    | view1   | db1         | public     | foo      | foo_id   | foo_id |
```

However, instead we just get this:

```
view_catalog|view_schema|view_name|table_catalog|table_schema|table_name|column_name
------------+-----------+---------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------
db1         | public    | view1   | db1        | public     | foo       | foo_fk
db1         | public    | view1   | db1        | public     | foo       | foo_a
db1         | public    | view1   | db1        | public     | foo       | foo_id
db1         | public    | view1   | db1        | public     | bar       | bar_a
db1         | public    | view1   | db1        | public     | bar       | bar_id
```

That means we don't get a mapping out of the box, but short of running parsing operations on `pg_views.definition` for the appropriate view, which would be inadvisable without a framework and arguably violate [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

### Workarounds

#### Hard-coding

The `WITH (...) INSERT` given earlier is fundamentally correct but feels cumbersome to use for database-views which just provide a simple identity-mapping of a few fields from other tables. (Things would get pretty intense indeed if the view did computations on the source-fields and they had to be transformed back before being added to the original columns, but that isn't the idea here).

#### Using a predictable naming format in the view's fields

We could certainly do something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS
        SELECT 
                foo_id AS foo__foo_id, 
                bar_id AS bar__bar_id, 
                foo_a AS foo__foo_a, 
                bar_a AS bar__bar_a 
        FROM (foo RIGHT JOIN bar ON foo.bar_id = bar.bar_id);
```

And then have the function use this format to determine where to place everything...

But in addition to reducing the legibility of the view, this would be similarly fragile to just hard-coding the `INSERT`-operations into a trigger because the function would choke if the column-names of the view were set up wrong. We could do a *view of a view* to fix the legibility-problem, but this would actually make the fragility-part a bit worse, which is really the main issue.

#### Just dealing with slightly fragile triggers and getting on with it

Even though I'm the main person dealing with the db-structure at this sort of level, I'm new to being this close to the database. So inflexible `INSTEAD`-triggers may just be fairly standard. If possible though, I'd still like a better solution so that things hold up decently when I'm out of the office and the other devs are still working, and for when I've moved on to another position.

### Notes

*Edit:* As [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3304426/patrick) correctly pointed out, there will be a performance impact with a trigger-function such as described above, given that `INSTEAD`s run on every row (unless I were to just cache the mapping and update it appropriately, which is messy in its own way). I should clarify that this trigger would mostly be a convenience for development-purposes as things are in a state of flux, and that would make replace with something simpler and faster for deployment. If anyone's got a way to do it (however slow), it would be a useful thing to have in my pocket if just for the purposes of learning about Postgre.

Especially for a deeper, real-world sort of case for this, it's probably stupid to try to intelligently compute the dependency-order of the various source-tables within the function. Since that shouldn't change much, I wouldn't mind providing some parameters to the trigger-function to tell it which tables should get new rows first.

As things got more complicated, it would probably also be fine to provide the trigger some information about how relations are merged together if it's 3 or 4 all shown together in a view. The function doesn't need to be so flexible as to tolerate table-names or primary-key column-names changing (without having its code tweaked); we're not building Skynet here. Regardless, you shouldn't need to worry about this given the simpler test-case above. I'll figure out the ugly stuff.

Also, assuming a level of consistency for foreign keys such as something like `something_fk` always translating to `something.something_id` is fine because this sort of thing should be regular across the database anyways.

As stated earlier, it we'll assume that views used with the `INSERT` trigger will not perform computations on the source-columns (or else to remain intuitive it would have to find the inverse of those operations before inserting values). Let's not go there.

#### Potentially-helpful resources

`pg_attribute` was a system table I found which may contain some useful stuff including information about the order in which a table's column's occur. `information_schema.columns` may also provide something along with `view_column_usage` as well (mentioned above).

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy solution for this and neither should there be a solution.

What you are proposing here implies that you will have a trigger function that is versatile enough to dynamically adapt to changing view definitions, as well as changes in the underlying tables. That is a bad idea for any number of reasons, of which I will give just two:

- If your developers are savvy (and privileged!) enough to be tinkering with table and view definitions, they should also know how to write a corresponding `INSTEAD OF` trigger for the view. A developer who knows DDL but not PL/pgSQL should be sent back to [PG school](http://www.postgresql.org/support/).
- A trigger function that is as flexible as you describe will be rather complex due to having to look up column names, source tables, map view columns to table columns, map values to columns, deal with constraints that the developers come up with, deal with column-level or table privileges, etc etc etc. It will be consequently slow. Since `INSTEAD OF` trigger functions always execute `FOR EACH ROW` they should be lean and fast; you are setting yourself up for a significant performance bottleneck.

How often do your table and view definitions change? Simply make a business rule in your shop that tables and views do not get changed unless and until a number of people have discussed and agreed upon the changes, including changes to the triggers. Test any proposed changes. Document it. Test it some more. And finally, test it much more before you roll out your application.

A shop where developers with apparently limited knowledge of PostgreSQL get to make changes to the data model that potentially break applications is not a shop that I would put my trust in.

Improve your developers and your development process, rather than PostgreSQL.

### What you can do

That said, careful design of tables and trigger functions can go a long way to reduce the number of trigger functions. The basic rule is to keep the triggers small and fast, letting them do only well-defined things, like propagating `INSERT`s to underlying tables of a view.

An `INSTEAD OF` trigger function is basically nothing more than a translation of a command operating on a view to one or more commands operating on the underlying tables. An `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger function on one view will be very similar to that on another view, so you can try an approach with templates. A template could look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION trf_ioi_#view# () RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  -- Put in INSERT statements on all the tables making up the view
  -- Example: Simple insert:
  -- INSERT INTO table (columns...)
  -- VALUES (NEW...);

  -- Get serial PK from 1 table to insert in other tables
  -- INSERT INTO table_PK (columns...)
  -- VALUES (NEW...)
  -- RETURNING pk INTO tid; (DECLARE tid before BEGIN)

  -- INSERT INTO table_FK (FK_column, other columns...)
  -- VALUES (tid, NEW...);

  RETURN NEW; -- to make trigger proceed; NULL to make trigger fail
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_ioi_#view#
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON #view#
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trf_ioi_#view#;
```

Replace `#view#` with the actual name of the view and you have boilerplate code that your developers can easily finish. Creating a trigger function like this really isn't very difficult, it is just a new trick that your developers have to learn. Usually, by the way, they will work with an existing trigger function so they only have to update the statements in the function body to reflect the changes in the view or underlying tables. Give them two days to play with PL/pgSQL and trigger functions and they should be well on their way.

Comment: This is about the kind of the answer I expected to get, but it is good advice. I'm currently part of a shop that up-until-now been used an off-the-shelf system (which was terrible), but we're now building our own deal. Some of the folks I need to be hands-on in the new database know loads about the actual data-structures we need, but are mostly self-taught and much more familiar with just dealing with things that are already built. Improving their knowledge and confidence with this kind of thing is a goal I'm working towards, but it's still nice to have tools to make things easier meanwhile.

Comment: See my updated answer. Do know that I am self-taught (ok, it's been 25 years since I first touched Oracle...), as are many of the established PostgreSQL users. PL/pgSQL really isn't all that hard, certainly not for developers with experience in procedural languages. Good luck with your transition!

Answer (score 0):

(Working on version Postgres 12.4)

**There is a way to see the underlying nullability for yourself with the following query:**

```
select vcu.column_name, c.is_nullable, c.data_type
from information_schema.view_column_usage vcu 
join information_schema."columns" c 
    on c.column_name = vcu.column_name 
    and c.table_name  = vcu.table_name 
    and c.table_schema  = vcu.table_schema 
    and c.table_catalog = vcu.table_catalog 
where view_name = 'your_view_here'
```

Although the OP was asking for 9.2, time marches on, and others who come here may like to use this.